# How to disable an input on change of other inputs (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, onchange, disabled-input

I'd like to add an attribute **disable**d to input **#stock** if whichever value of **#option_name-x** is not empty. My code works only if I enter something into *#option_value_1*, but it doesn't work if I leave *#option_value_1* empty and enter something into *#option_value_2* or the following. In other words, the code works with the first input only.

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="option_name[]" id="option_name_1" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="option_name[]" id="option_name_2" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="option_name[]" id="option_name_3" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="option_name[]" id="option_name_4" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="option_name[]" id="option_name_5" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Stock (*disabled if any option_name field is NOT EMPTY*)<br>
        <input name="stock" id="stock" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>


// on input change
    $("input").change(function() {
// i want to react on whichever input with id starting with "option_name"
        if($("[id^='option_name']").val() !== "") {
            $("#stock").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $("#stock").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work perfectly for you, always remember `on` is better in this scenario, and you might need to execute it on `paste` as well

```
// on input change
$("input").on("change paste keyup", function() {
  var optionsInputHavevalue = $("[id^='option_name']").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().trim().length > 0 ;
  }).length > 0;
  $("#stock").prop('disabled', optionsInputHavevalue);
}).change();
```

working bin can be found here.
https://jsbin.com/zojukij/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It works opposite. I'd like to add an attribute DISABLED if #option_name IS NOT EMPTY.

Comment: Corrected, please check now

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get inputs i.e. `$("[id^='option_name']")` have value and [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set property.

```js
// on input change
$("input").change(function() {
  var optionsInputHavevalue = $("[id^='option_name']").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().trim().length > 0 ;
  }).length > 0;
  $("#stock").prop('disabled', !optionsInputHavevalue);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="option_name[]" id="option_name_1" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="option_name[]" id="option_name_2" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="option_name[]" id="option_name_3" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="option_name[]" id="option_name_4" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="option_name[]" id="option_name_5" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Stock (*disabled if any option_name field is NOT EMPTY*)<br>
      <input name="stock" id="stock" type="text" >
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```